# how to add gradient into Border Bottom

Tags: javascript, php, css

I was able to change the gradient background by using the image + got the css snippet from codepen (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMdvdJ)

But the box-shadow thing with the border is not changing!

I want the underline to be gradient Instead of a single color.

I use good life theme and I tried a lot to change but the bottom border is not changing its color to the gradient.

```css
.post  .post-content p a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #566ce7;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 #566ce7;    
} 
.post .post-content p a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #566ce7 0%, #764ba2 100%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>
      <a href="#">Link here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.digitalassetsy.com/about/ ( link to my website page )

please help.

Regards,

Aleena.

Answer (score 0):

On `hover` you need to turn off the box shadow and the border

```css
.post .post-content p a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #566ce7;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 #566ce7;
}

.post .post-content p a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #566ce7 0%, #764ba2 100%);
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>
      <a href="#">Link here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is whaht you are trying to achieve

```css
.post  .post-content {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #566ce7;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 #566ce7;    
} 
.post .post-content p a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #566ce7 0%, #764ba2 100%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>
      <a href="#">Link here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `border` for bottom line, you will need to use `border-image` to apply gradient to the border. I don't see any use of `box-shadow` here

```css
.post .post-content p a {
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #566ce7 0%, #764ba2 100%) 5;
}

.post .post-content p a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #566ce7 0%, #764ba2 100%);
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>
      <a href="#">Link here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```